# Have Democrats or Republicans held up aid to Israel before, in the hope of getting a broader deal on other legislation?

Tags: united-states, israel, legislative-process, foreign-aid, logrolling

Biden [has](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/johnson-rips-bidens-threat-veto-17-billion-israel-aid-bill-act-betrayal) threatened to veto a bill that would provide Israel-only aid, because that would scupper Democrats' attempts at getting a broader deal, including more funding for Ukraine etc. (Predictably, Republicans have labelled this threat an "act of betrayal".)

Was aid to Israel ever held up before (either by Republicans or Democrats) in this kind of situation, hoping to get a broader legislative deal on something [else] that only one party favored?

Comment: I can't cite chapter and verse but I would be stunned if the answer was no. This is how the U.S. legislative process works on everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q: *Have Democrats or Republicans held up aid to Israel before, in the hope of getting a broader deal on other legislation?*

Yes, but this delay didn't last very long.

On July 31, 2014, Republicans opposed a "border bill" that included support for Israel's Iron Dome due to objections concerning an immigration policy relating to unaccompanied minors. That bill *died* on the floor of the Senate when the cloture vote failed.

The following day, August 1, 2014, the Senate amended the text of a previously passed House Joint Resolution to fund Iron Dome, separately. The House agreed to the amendment. [H.J.Res.76 - Emergency Supplemental Appropriations Resolution, 2014](https://www.congress.gov/bill/113th-congress/house-joint-resolution/76) became law August 4, 2014.

The bill that *died* —

[S.2648 - Emergency Supplemental Appropriations Act, 2014](https://www.congress.gov/bill/113th-congress/senate-bill/2648)

> Emergency Supplemental Appropriations Act, 2014 - Appropriates supplemental funds for FY2014 to specified federal agencies and programs to respond to the increased apprehensions of unaccompanied children and minors along the southwestern border, fight wildfires, and **support Israel's Iron Dome anti-missile defense system**. [Emboldening added.]

The objection by Republicans —

[Senate advances border bill](https://www.politico.com/story/2014/07/senate-advances-border-bill-109540), 07/31/2014

> Key Senate Republicans, including moderates and GOP lawmakers who wrote a sweeping immigration overhaul bill last year, have already said they oppose the Democratic measure. Their primary objection: It leaves intact a 2008 anti-trafficking law that, in practice, has made it more difficult to deport children from Central America now arriving at the U.S.-Mexico border.

Comment: I would suspect that while this may be the most recent example, it is probably not the only example since 1948.

Comment: @ohwilleke - The "kind of situation" in the body of the Q, places a constraint on the answer. I found some examples where presidents *threatened* to veto Israel aid legislation based on its terms or conditions in Israel, but none of those seemed to be a similar "kind of situation".